# My contact form is not sending email

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I've been trying to set up a contact form to send info to my email. I've checked the code and there's no syntax error or anything but I'm not receiving any test email. Can you please help me out?

Here's the HTML:

```
    <!--Start of Contact Form-->
    <div class="large-7 medium-10 small-12 medium-centered large-centered column">
        <div class="row">
            <form method="post" action="email2.php">

                    <input type="text" name="name" class="defaultText" title="your name">
                    <input type="text" name="email" class="defaultText" title="your email address">


                    <textarea name="comments1" class="defaultText" title="Tell us about your business"></textarea>
                    <textarea name="comments2" class="defaultText" title="How can we help?"></textarea>


               <div class="large-7 medium-10 small-12 medium-centered large-centered column">
                    <input type="submit" name="send message" value="Send Message">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of Contact Form-->
```

and here's the script:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $name = $_POST['name'] ;
  $email = $_POST['email'] ;
  $comments1 = $_POST['comments1'] ;
  $comments2 = $_POST['comments2'] ; 
  mail("info@muzedimage.com", $name, $email, $comments1, $comments2
 , "From:" . $email);
  echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.muzedimage.com'</script>";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out,
  {
  echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.muzedimage.com/contact'</script>";
  }
?>
```

I would really appreciate the help guys.

Comment: The issue is how you assign those variables to their specific arguments. The headers you are supplying are incorrect and the mail is rejected due to this fact. Please [read more about mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: do people just guess at what arguments a function takes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have passed wrong arguments to your mail function. Please read the `mail()` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

The correct format is

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

In your case below is the correct code.

```
$to      = 'info@muzedimage.com';
$email   = $_POST['email'] ;
$subject = 'add some subject'; // no subject could lead to email being flagged as spam
$comments1 = $_POST['comments1'] ;
$comments2 = $_POST['comments2'] ; 
$message = $comments1 .  "\n\n" . $comments2;
$headers = "From: $email";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

You need to use comments how you want to. In this case I assumed that they both consist the main message.

Hope that helps. And always read documentation!!

Comment: @user3213485 seems like you figured out already. good luck and happy coding.